# when migrate the table throws exception in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Help me to resolve

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found

Comment: local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found in /home/css/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/MySqlConnection.php:65

Comment: have u configure the db ?

Comment: @pradeep yes i configured db in env file.

Comment: @murugesh did you resolve your problem by the given answers? or are you still experiencing issues?

Answer (score 1):

Did you require the `doctrine/dbal` package?

If you haven't, run the following.

`composer require doctrine/dbal`

Read the section about **modifying columns**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#modifying-columns

**Taken from laravel documentation**

*Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries needed to make the specified adjustments to the column:*

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer require doctrine/dbal`

Then

Run `composer update`.

It should fix the issue.

Comment: composer update is not required.. It updates all dependencies. He might not want that. composer require is enough.

Comment: I am not certain, But `require` is adds the required package.

Comment: if you run composer install doctrine/dbal, it install the package, without updating the other dependencies.

Comment: If you have a strict setup, where you depend on specific versions of packages. You should use update, unless you are certain that it wont break your current code base.

Comment: @Gammer Yes i can able to track logs  after composer update in applications.[laravel logs]

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require doctrine/dbal:^2.12.1
```

They changed the class path on dbal 3, so you will need an older version.

Answer (score -1):

You need to generate the migration properly and then only it will work when you try to migrate the tables

To create a migration you need to use the make:migration

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

The new migration will be placed in your database/migrations directory. Each migration file name contains a timestamp which allows Laravel to determine the order of the migrations.

The --table and --create options may also be used to indicate the name of the table and whether the migration will be creating a new table. These options pre-fill the generated migration stub file with the specified table:

For example,

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users

php artisan make:migration add_votes_to_users_table --table=users
```

For more information's to read about [migrating tables in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations)

Comment: this solution has nothing to do with the OP's error.